# Windows 10 automatically creating new profile upon restart

Tags: windows-10

I am not sure if this is really the problem but it seems that Windows 10 is automatically creating a new profile for me with the same credentials every time I restart my computer. I can still log on with my old credentials but some apps like Slack and Dropbox aren't there anymore and needs to be re-downloaded, MS Outlook is requiring me to set up my profile from start with nothing synced, etc. etc. It's treating me like a new user with each login. I am super frustrated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information for sure knowing what is happening. But from my previous experiences, I could assume that what you are seeing is, Windows login you into a temporary profile. This happens when there is something corrupted on your original profile, and windows log you into the last know working profile. After logout, nothing is saved.

Sometimes it is possible to recover the profile, but sometimes it could be impossible. Wherever is the case it is better backup anything that is possible in case that you need to delete and create a new one.

Google for windows temporary profile recovery as they are many techniques depending of the cause. Here are a couple of samples:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/you-have-been-logged-in-with-a-temporary-profile/20ed22a5-8338-4578-84bc-f0a8e77aa15d

https://winaero.com/blog/windows-10-youve-been-signed-in-with-a-temporary-profile/

Comment: It's not a temporary profile (or at least doesn't seem like it). I am still logging on to the same account with the same password. It's just that the files are missing every time I restart the computer.

Comment: So after researching this more, it seems like for whatever reason my user account has been corrupted. The only choice I think I have is to create a second user account.

Comment: Windows tries to detect the corruption ahead before granting access, but if the corruption happens on a later stage, it will not give all those startup warnings but the end result is the same, with a locked profile. As I suggested before, backup everything from the current profile, deactivate any personal licenses then create a new one. If it's a domain account, you will need to delete the profile before trying to use the same login information and of course you need to be connected on the same network of the Active Directory.

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you know a better answer, please share it or point what bothers you. The provided answer follows the most common reason of this fault.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you. But I upvoted and now you're back to par

Comment: @MilesToGoBeforeISleep, thanks for it!! I understand for no votes on, but downvotes without explanation, is completely useless for everybody. Also, I will understand if I am suggesting something dangerous or the answer is way out of context.

Comment: @MilesToGoBeforeISleep, because you can still login on the profile I will say that it's damaged (maybe not corrupted). The odds of repair are low by looking the success rate on other forums. Also, I personally, had a profile misbehaving on a laptop that the SSD was failing. Maybe, also it will be good idea to run a disk scan.

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same problem..This problem nos called Temporary Profile Login.  You can just follow this YouTube Video [Fix Temporary Profile Login Error in Windows 10](https://youtu.be/uMT8BiWjNFA)

If you like reading go read this article [FIX Temporary Profile on Windows 10](https://bitactro.com/temporary-profile-windows-10/)

I hope I have answered this question.